# VAIO SVE17122CXB keyboard backlit not working - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, sony, keyboard-backlight

The keyboard backlit for my VAIO SVE17122CXB is not working.

Is there a solution? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I don't care how you came to replace `0` with `o`, but I suggest not doing this when talking about technical matter.

Comment: I have the same problem [Asked here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475711/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw) but I could not fix that.