# Error on installing upstream kernel

Tags: kernel, update-manager, upstream

I tried to install latest upstream kernel(**linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb**) from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc2-utopic/) but installation failed with this error:

```
user@user-pc:~$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 228154 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) over (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic:
 linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic depends on linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
```

I tried to install with using `GDebi` and I get this error:

```
user@user-pc:~$ sudo gdebi linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2
```

After that I saw this icon on top bar:

[image]

by right-click on it, this error message written in it:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or apt-get in a teminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was :'Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unment dependences

and three another options such as `Show updates`, `Show Notifications` and `Preferences`. I click on `Show updates` and now this window start to upgrade the Distribution

[image]

Now that finished with this window shown:

[image]

I choice <kbd>Remove</kbd> and popup window asks "restart to complete", and after restart I tried to install again this kernel but I get the same errors that I mentioned in above.

#### Here is the output of try install again with some error:

```
user@user-pc:~$ cd /home/user/install-kernel
user@user-pc:~/install-kernel$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
[sudo] password for user: 
(Reading database ... 255488 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2 (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) over (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) over (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) over (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
Setting up linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2 (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304-updates/304.117/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304-updates/304.117/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.17.0-031700rc2-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
user@user-pc:~/install-kernel$
```

Comment: Obligatory XKCD comic: http://xkcd.com/754/

Comment: Is there something special you need to try to install a precompíled kernel out of the official repository and with no guarantee to work on a daily basis to begin with?

Comment: @xangua Yse I have a problem with keyboard back-light that I asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475711/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw) and through a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16735) with [@Whaaaaaat] this problem can BEST be described as a bug. And I post this problem as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1362046) and there suggest to me [install upstream kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1362046/comments/19) to test my issue if fix with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing this file:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc2-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_all.deb

It should satisfy the dependancy.

You should have these installed:

- `linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb`
- `linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc2_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_all.deb`
- `linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc2-generic_3.17.0-031700rc2.201408251935_amd64.deb`

All of the files above are available from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc2-utopic/).

***NOTE: BUGS ARE TO BE EXPECTED!*** It is a testing kernel and is therefore very very very unstable.

[[Src]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels)

Comment: @KasiyA Was there any progess?

Comment: @KasiyA If you installed `headers-generic` already, install `headers`. If you haven't installed `image`, install that now followed by `headers`.

Comment: @KasiyA You need to install all packages first. Or even better, make a folder and put all of the kernel DEB files in them, `cd` into that folder, and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`