# SONY VAIO Turn off backlight, locked windows partition, need help downloading java SEMIDUPLICATE SOS STAT

Tags: windows, windows-8, vaio, sony, backlight

Sony Vaio SVF15N17CXB

[Turn off keyboard back-light Sony (VAIO SVF1521DCXW)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475711/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw)

Hello all,

Total newbie, tried to dualboot but ubuntu locked up my windows partition,
my windows is locked and i need 10 Reps to post pics from gparted.

Linux aaron 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I need help turning off the backlight and its draining my juice faster than a buggati, had 10 hr battery life, now i cant  get past 7-8 max.

I cant even download java for my computer science class please help!

I tried downloading the qtmake files from a website and im lost

Comment: One topic per question please

Comment: Install xbacklight and use `xbacklight -set 0` to turn off the light

Comment: @bodhi.zazen  How do i unlock a partition, i already tried umount /dev/sda

Comment: I do not know if locked means it is already mounted or if it is a permissions problem. /dev/sda is the entire hard drive, you need to specify a partition - /dev/sda1 for example ...

Comment: see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions