# Sony vaio Keyboard back-light svf1531b4e

Tags: 14.04, vaio, sony, keyboard-backlight

I have a sony vavio svf1531b4e and I  I want to turn OFF its keyboard back-light. Please help me it's important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off keyboard back-light Sony (VAIO SVF1521DCXW)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475711/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug in Ubuntu. I'm not sure if it has a fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1362046

Comment: Had seen this site and did what it said but it has worked for me .